# how to count single or double quotes

Tags: c, algorithm, text-analysis, string-algorithm

my problem is to be able to count the number of single or double quotes in a string in c.
example

```
        String            Single Quote Count        Double Quote Count
     'hello world'                2                      0
     'hell'o world'               3                      0

     "hello world"                0                      2
     "hello" world"               0                      3
```

user enters string, i take by gets() function, and then i need this counter to further analyse the string.

It was easier when i had to count '|'in my string, for example

```
        String            | Count        
     hello | world           1            
     hello | wo|rld          2
```

so my function was as simple as :

```
 int getNumPipe(char* cmd){
  int  num = 0;
  int i;
     for(i=0;i<strlen(cmd);i++){
       if(cmd[i]=='|'){ //if(condition)
       num++;
      }
     }

 return num;
}
```

But now that i have to analyse the quotes i dont know what to put for the if(condition)

```
          if(cmd[i]==''')??
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23169810/how-to-count-nuumber-of-single-or-double-quotes-in-a-string-in-c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

simple-escape-sequence:
Anytime you need to express any of these 11 characters as a constant in code, use the following:

```
'\\' (backslash)
'\'' (quote)
'\"' (double quote)
'\?' (question mark)
'\a' (alarm)
'\b' (backspace)
'\f' (form feed)
'\n' (new line)
'\r' (carriage return)
'\t' (horizontal tab)
'\v' (vertical tab)
```

Good time for code re-use:

```
int getNumPipe(const char* cmd, char match) {
  int  num = 0;
  while (*cmd != '\0') {
    if (*cmd == match) num++;
    cmd++;
    }
  return num;
}

...
char s[100];
fgets(s, sizeof s, stdin);
printf(" \" occurs %d times.\n", getNumPipe(s, '\"'));
printf(" \' occurs %d times.\n", getNumPipe(s, '\''));
```

Answer (score 5):

To make a char containing a single quote, you have to escape it. Otherwise, it's treated as the end of the character.

```
int numSingle = 0, numDouble = 0;
int i;
for (i = 0; cmd[i] != 0; i++) { // Don't call strlen() every time, it's N**2
    if (cmd[i] == '\'') {
        numSingle++;
    } else if (cmd[i] == '"') {
        numDouble++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to use a backslash as an escape character before  single quote (Like `\'` ) or double quote(Like  `\"` ).So,you have to use following statements to check and count :

```
    if (cmd[i] == '\'')  numOfSingleQuote++;
    else if (cmd[i] == '\"')  numOfDoubleQuote++;
```

Checkout the link for more : [Escape sequences in C](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_sequences_in_C)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use an escape sequence.

```
if(cmd[i]== '\'') {
    //do something
}
```

You could also use the ascii values. 27 for ' and 22 for " in hexadecimal.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape it

```
if (cmd[i] =='\'')
    cntSingle++;
else if (cmd[i] =='\"')
    cntDouble++;
```

Comment: You don't need to escape the double quote.

Comment: Also, you're not counting them separately.

Comment: @Barmar use double quote without escaping with cause you trouble when using char arrays. Also previously I didn't answer the counting way but the way he should escape the character because he didn't know that

Comment: This is a single char, not a string. You only have to escape the character that's used to delimit it -- escape single quotes in chars, double quotes in strings.